# Is $x^x$ always equals $e^{x\log x}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let suppose that we have a real number $x\in \mathbb{R}$. How to express $x^x$ in term of elementary functions? I mean when $x>0$, $x^x=e^{x\log x}$. Also when $x=0$, one can extend it and use $x^x=e^{x\log x}$. Am I right? What happens when $x<0$? Is it defined? Cannot be expressed with elementary functions?

Comment: What is $$0^0?$$  and if $x<0$ does $$x^x$$ always remain real?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee He is probably using the "usual" definition $0^0=1$, which holds here, if we take $\lim x\to0^+$ in the exponential defintion.

Comment: @op You can define it to be $e^{x\log(x)}$ *in* $\mathbb C$. In $\Bbb R$, we can't define things like $$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I supposed that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\log x=0$

Comment: @Sabyasachi I do not understand. If we define it in $\mathbb{C}$ and we have $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$. Why it would be a problem in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Continuing the last example, in $\Bbb C$ it becomes, $\sqrt2i$, and the exponential definition gives, $$e^{\frac12\log(-2)}$$ which equals $\sqrt2i$ if you take the proper branch.

Comment: @zighalo because $x^x\not\in \Bbb R$ if $x\lt0$(I mean not     always $\in\Bbb R$)

Comment: @Sabyasachi Ah ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that $x^x=e^{x\log x}$, but this can be done only for $x>0$, because the expression on the right hand side is defined only there.

At $0$ the expression *can* be given the value $1$, but of course this doesn't guarantee that the function is continuous at $0$, unless you prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{x\log x}=1
$$
which is indeed true. Use the limit from the right, if you want: I always assume that the limit is computed through neighborhoods of the fixed point *in the domain of definition of the function*.

For somebody $0^0$ is not defined (I have never understood why). If you're among them, then you can only define the function $x^x$ for $x>0$.

In the complex numbers (and also for negative values of $x$) the expression $x^x$ is not well defined, as it can have infinitely many values.

Comment: I have seen a lot of people thinking that $x^x$ doesn't have a value for negative, the real problem is it has *a lot* of values. +1

Comment: @Sabyasachi $x^x$ is single valued when $x=-1$ and double valued when $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @FlybyNight maybe you mean $x=-1/2$

Comment: @Sabyasachi No. $(1/2)^{1/2}=\pm\sqrt{2}/2$ since both satisfy $x^2=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @FlybyNight I am pretty sure $(1/2)^{1/2}$ is *defined* to be positive, no?

Comment: @Sabyasachi $\sqrt{2}$ is defined to be the positive solution to the equation $x^2=2$, while $2^{1/2}$ is any solution to the equation $x^2=2$. I suppose this might just be a matter of notation. If you take $\sqrt{2}$ and $2^{1/2}$ to mean the same thing then what you say is exactly right. For me $2^{1/2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are different.

Comment: @FlybyNight I take $2^{1/2}$ to mean $\sqrt2$, *specifically* to make $x^y$ well defined for $x,y\ge0$

Answer (score 2):

The laws of logs $\log(xy) \equiv \log x + \log y$, $\log \frac{x}{y} \equiv \log x - \log y$ and $\log x^y \equiv y\log x$ are only valid when $x$ and $y$ are positive. The argument which shows that $x^x = \mathrm{e}^{x\log x}$ is only valid when $x>0$.